# How would you use FRAs to find out how much Central Banks would cut/hike by?

Tags: interest-rates, forward-rate, central-banking

Let's say you have The FRAs 1x4F, 2x5F, 3x6F, 4x7F, 5x8F... (meaning 3 months rate today, 3 months rate in 1 month, etc..) at 5.5, 5.5, 5.6, 5.55, 5.55.

Assume today's date is 20/09/2019.

You also have central bank meetings on 21/11/2019, 15/01/2020, 26/03/2020

How would you use this to predict the central bank's decisions at those dates?

Comment: As per the answer below, this might be helpful: https://www.economics-finance.org/jefe/fin/KeaslerGoffpaper.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You do not directly use FRAs to predict central bank rate moves. Instead you tend to use fed fund ois rates because they are more directly reliable as a proxy for those rates.

Otherwise you might first FRAs to estimate the ffois rates and then from there estimate the central bank rates

Answer (score 0):

Just look at meeting date OIS. There should be broker screens and dealer runs for these for liquid markets.